# How to stop execution of Controller with $routeChangeStart in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

I am setting session on login and after that I am preventing LoginCtrl to be called as it is resetting session.
I have a setup of routes where if any undefined route is called it takes to `/login` But to avoid this on login I am redirecting using the following code, which seems to be not working

I am also using `event.preventDefault();` but no use.
LoginCtrl is unstoppable and regardless of `$location.path()` being changed to some other controller it is still executed.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'SessionService', function ($rootScope, $location, sessionService) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {
//      if((next.redirectTo == '/login' || next.originalPath == '/login') && sessionService.isLogin()){
      if((next.templateUrl == 'views/login.html') && sessionService.isLogin()){
          event.preventDefault();
          $location.path('/settings/resetpassword');
          return;
        }

    });
}]);
```

Following is LoginCtrl.

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $location, loginService, SessionService, ShowApiErrors) {
    $scope.init = function () {
      SessionService.resetMySession();
    };
    $scope.init();

});
```

Router :-

```
$routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        redirectTo: '/login'
     })
    ....
     .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
      });
```

Comment: You can add `resolve` property with `promise` when defining `route` parameter, and reject promise when you need it. `$routeChangeError` will be fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of more hard googling I found [this url](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5581) It tells that I should rather use `$locationChangeStart`
It has the ability to stop the execution right away and I redirected back to my intended route.

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next) {
      if(next.match('/login') && sessionService.isLogin()){
        $location.path('/after-login-path');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Under LoginCtrl, why don't you check if the user is already logged-in before logging out. Or any other condition which would prevent the user from logging out. As far as I know you cannot stop a controller from executing.

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $location, loginService, SessionService, ShowApiErrors) {
    $scope.init = function () {
          if(!SessionService.isLogin()) {
               SessionService.resetMySession();
          }
    };
    $scope.init();

});
```